# Spring How to inject value to Queue by XML

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

Using Spring Framework, I want to create a bean object of type `Person`, and this bean object have a `queue` property of type `Queue<Integer>`, how to inject value to the property through XML?

The spring version is 4.3

The reference document is https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.25.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-class-ctor

but I can't find queue.

I try to use `<bean>` element, but the property `queue` of the bean is empty.

The Object is as follow

```
public class People {
    private int id;
    private Queue<Integer> queue;
    // add constructor

    // add get and set
}
```

The applicationContext.xml is as follow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="..." class="...">
        <property name="queue">
            <bean class="java.util.ArrayDeque">
                //How should I add values to the queue object
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: What do you mean "property can't filled.", is there any error message?

Comment: @samabcde I can't find how to configure queue. How should I add values to the queue object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By referring to [Spring support on collection](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.25.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-collection-elements), the `List`, `Set` and `Map` interface can be injected by `<list/>`, `<set/>` and `<map/>` elements. The `Queue` interface is not supported. However, since `ArrayDeque` has a constructor for `Collection`, we can inject values from a `List` to `ArrayDeque` through [`<constructor-arg/>`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.25.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-ctor-arguments-resolution) elements.

The following example demonstrates how to add value to the `ArrayDeque`.

*applicationContext.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="people" class="spring.People">
        <property name="queue">
            <bean class="java.util.ArrayDeque">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <list value-type="java.lang.Integer">
                        <value>1</value>
                        <value>2</value>
                        <value>3</value>
                    </list>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

*Main Class*

```
package spring;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class InjectQueueApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
        People people = context.getBean("people", People.class);
        System.out.println(people.getQueue().toString());
    }
}
```